# Why is there seemingly no information on FIMS?

Tags: england-and-wales, police, investigation

Why is there seemingly no information on FIMS?

Why is there seemingly no publicly available information on FIMS?

FIMS is the police's facial identification manager software used by officers to identify unknown suspects whose likenesses are captured on CCTV etc. A friendly police officer on the street told me all about it though when asked what it might have stood for he guessed facial information management system. From my searching there appears to be but a single page about the net's transitioning the platform to Microsoft's Azure cloud infrastructure service like a lone press release or something. And really not much else like all the publicly released internal system usage guidance one might expect, even if it would typically be occasionally redacted at especially sensitive parts.

Is there something about the FIMS system that makes it especially sensitive or otherwise exempt from public understanding of its working?

Comment: have you tried searching for "UK police facial recognition software" as well as FIMS?

Comment: Yes, but it seems to return a lot of information on what is apparently a separate system of digital/ai based facial recognition/identification, rather than the tinder-style interface that's presented to officers by FIMS for them to perform manual identification of unknown suspects.